# What versions of .Net framework are installed when you install .Net 3.5 SP1?

Tags: .net-3.5

I'm trying to confirm which versions of the .Net framework are installed when you just install 3.5 SP1.  I know that with 3.5, 2.0 + SP1 and 3.0 + SP1 are installed.  I have a client that has a 1.1 app and I want to know what version is loaded when it runs if 1.1 isn't installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep apart the CLR (Common Language Runtime) version, and the .NET framework version.

- .NET framework 1.0 and 1.1 are built on **CLR 1.0**
- .NET framework versions 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and 3.5 SP1 are all built on the **CLR 2.0** - the newer framework versions are simply additional functionality delivered in the forms of additional assemblies and namespaces - but the core of the runtime system is still the 2.0 CLR
- .NET framework 4 is built on the new **CLR 4.0** - so this is a totally new kid in town

If you install .NET framework 3.5 SP1, you get:

- the base CLR version 2.0
- the .NET framework functionalities for 2.0 (plus all SP's), 3.0 (plus all SP's), 3.5, 3.5 SP1

You do **not** get any support for the CLR 1.0 (.NET 1.0 / 1.1) - if you need that, you'll have to install it separately.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [page on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) that describes the [.NET Framework Versions and Dependencies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx) that would probably be of interest.

Most specifically to your question:

> The .NET Framework version 3.5 builds upon versions 2.0 and 3.0 and their service packs. The .NET Framework version 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1) updates version 3.5 assemblies and includes new servicing updates for versions 2.0 and 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

It wont load any version. 'coz for 1.1 you need to install .NET Framework 1.1 otherwise your app wont run